# Most suitable ionic component for linked inputs or a plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an app on ionic 3, and the UI proposal have this view to verify SMS.

Is any way to do this without using 4 different inputs and linking them with JS? a plugin or something?

[image: UI Proposal]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a codepen  that is similar

https://codepen.io/nirarazi/pen/ZGovQo

but the magic is in the js

```
    $(function() {
  'use strict';

  var body = $('body');

  function goToNextInput(e) {
    var key = e.which,
      t = $(e.target),
      sib = t.next('input');

    if (key != 9 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    if (key === 9) {
      return true;
    }

    if (!sib || !sib.length) {
      sib = body.find('input').eq(0);
    }
    sib.select().focus();
  }

  function onKeyDown(e) {
    var key = e.which;

    if (key === 9 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57)) {
      return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  function onFocus(e) {
    $(e.target).select();
  }

  body.on('keyup', 'input', goToNextInput);
  body.on('keydown', 'input', onKeyDown);
  body.on('click', 'input', onFocus);

})
```

Comment: Hi there, with the code from link above, did anyone found, that when code is entered quickly, like all 4 numbers in one second, some are skipped? E.g. when I enter 1234, it shows 13_4. I tried to log keyup key code, but there are right numbers 49,50,51,52. Do you have any idea, what is causing this issue and how to solve it?